# How can I raise my effective Caster Level to make dispelling my magic more difficult?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, divine

I'm trying to minimize the cleric (and related PrCs) levels in a build while still getting enough Caster Level to avoid being dispelled by, say, a lucky *chain dispel* cast by an Inquisitor.

I've already considered several items:

- The Ring of Enduring Arcana (CM) gives a +4 CL for resisting to dispel only.
- The Orange Prism Ioun Stone gives a +1 CL
- The Prayer Bead of Karma gives a +4 CL
- The MIC has an Ankh that makes me spend spell slots to get a +4 CL on the next spell
- SpC has a magic tattoo that gives another +1 CL

The Practiced Spellcaster feat helps, but I'm trying to get less cleric levels in order to gain fighter feats, so (while still advantageous) it is a last resort.

**Is there anything else I could do to become undispellable (save for antimagic or disjunctions)?**

Comment: Are you interested in *class levels*? I am thinking of the +2 CL offered by the *High Priest* mask of the [Master of Masks](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20070105a&page=3) class but doubting whether it interests you given your mention of saving feats...

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/how-can-a-non-epic-spellcaster-create-a-colossal-animated-object

Comment: @MatthieuM. Mentioning it won't hurt, though you're right. Unless the class really gives you way more than it loses to Fighter (which is hard) I will consider it. I left out alignment and deity on purpose to let people state theyr methods: even if I then don't want to use them, I will however upvote and accept based on what I asked, not on what I can or can not use on this specific character.

Comment: I edited the title to bring it in line with the question.  Previously, the title at a glance read more as a general help, "Ho do I increase my caster level?" from a learning to play perspective.  I think this makes it more clear from the main page and search results what the question is actually about.  As always, feel free to undo the revision if you don't agree with the changes.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To tilt the frame slightly, instead of increasing your caster levels to ridiculous heights, you can try to avoid getting your spells dispelled by just becoming immune to spells that dispel magic. While many spells dispel magic, unless the DM is Dumpster-diving to deliberately overcome your shored-up defenses, you only really need worry about the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*dispel magic*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 223) and the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*greater dispel magic*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagicGreater.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 223).<sup>1</sup> The basic items that help do this:

- The [***ring of counterspells***](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#counterspells) (*DMG* 230) (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.) counters once the spell that's cast in it after which it can be reloaded with the same or a different spell.
- The ***ring of spell-battle*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 127) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.), in addition to other effects, grants the wearer 1/day the ability to redirect a spell that the wearer's identified that's cast on him at a different target within a limited range.
- The magic weapon special ability ***spellblade*** (*Player's Guide to Faerûn* 120) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) is keyed when created to one specific spell (like *dispel magic* or *greater dispel magic* but not both), and when that spell is cast upon the weapon's wielder he can *either* redirect the spell to the originator *or* have the spell dissipate.<sup>2</sup>

Note that of these only the *ring of spell battle* can, after its fashion, defend against area dispel effects.

Other similar magic items likely exist—as do shenanigans (like finding someone with the feat Craft Contingent Spell (*Complete Arcane* 77) and paying him to ensorcell you appropriately)—, but the above list probably holds the most convenient and palatable solutions.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Other spells that dispel magic include (but by no means are limited to) the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *arcane turmoil* [abjur] (*CM* 96),
the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *dispelling touch* [abjur] (*Player's Handbook II* 110), the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *blackstaff* [trans] (*Magic of Faerûn* 81), the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *chain dispel* [abjur] (*Player's Handbook II* 106-7), and the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell *reaving dispel* [abjur] (*Spell Compendium* 169-70).
<sup>**2**</sup> Many weapons can be wielded—often simultaneously—an *not* occupy a creature's hands. I suggest multiple surprise weapons (*Complete Scoundrel* 109-10).

Comment: I integrated the ring's name in the question, thanks. I mostly fear walls of dispels, chain dispels and the dreaded reaving dispel. My whole character is useless if dispelled and greatly handicapped if one of his key spells goes down. The ring of spell-battle (which is great against area dispels) only works if the caster is in range... and in case of walls of dispel magic, the caster might not even be alive anymore. Your answer made me think of the crown of sorcerous power (name?) that absorbs 10 levels of spells cast on you (which you then have to cast to free the slots).

Comment: Usually, I am for cheap stuff because that's the point where most folks play, but if you can afford the crazy, I'll dig a little deeper. Is the DM seriously throwing out *chain dispels*? Man, I did that once against the PCs and, seriously, never again. Resolving that one spell took, like, an hour.

Comment: I've seen walls of dispel being used. When you party with folks several levels lower, debuffing the bigger threat (me) is an option and I don't want to need to pay for permanency over Tongues or Read Magic again.

Answer (score 1):

**Class Ability:**

The [Master of Masks](https://web.archive.org/web/20180316150937/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20070105a&page=3) (Complete Scoundrel), gives you the ability to craft and wear *Persona Masks*. You may only wear one mask at a time, and at level 1 you may craft two.

Of particular interest is the *High Priest* mask, which gives (among other benefits):

> Your caster level is treated as two higher for the purpose of casting divine spells (up to a maximum of your character level).

Mechanically, its bar to entry is somewhat high (8 in *Bluff*, *Disguise* and *Perform (act)*; 4 languages spoken).

Of note: at 2nd, 4th, 7th, and 9th level you also get to advance one spell-casting class; thus if your goal is to minimize the spell-casting progression you should only take 1 level or (as you mentioned) replace other divine caster classes appropriately.

Comment: Or 2 levels by taking one less cleric level.

Comment: @Zachiel: Indeed, you could even take 3 levels (getting 4 masks) if you are willing to drop a Cleric level since the 3rd level does not progress your spell-casting class, etc... If BAB matters to you though, beware, MoM is 1/2 BAB like a Wizard/Sorcerer.